# Wordpress specific order of echo post meta checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm a php newbie and a first time poster.

I am working on a wordpress site where I need a discography.
I have successfully:
Created my custom post type : Albums
Added custom meta boxes and custom fields to admin post edit page
Made an archive page and echoed all the custom field meta.
http://squarerecording.com/albums/

One of my custom fields is a series of 5 checkboxes: the last line of each album on that archive page

```
array(
                'name'    => 'Services Rendered',
                'desc'    => 'field description (optional)',
                'id'      => $prefix . 'services',
                'type'    => 'multicheck',
                'options' => array(
                    'R' => 'Recorded',
                    'Mi' => 'Mixed',
                    'Ma' => 'Mastered',
                    'P' => 'Produced',
                    'RMV' => 'Re-mastered for vinyl',
                ),
            ),
```

although I have successfully echoed the "Services Rendered" in a comma separated format, the order is different for each post (P,RMV,R,Mi,Ma-for the first one, P,Ma,Mi,R,RMV-for the second, etc.)

Here is the code for the archive page that outputs "Services Rendered":

```
<?php $key="sqr_services";  get_post_meta($post->ID, $key); 
 $sqr_services = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key );
 $comma_sep_services = implode(",", $sqr_services );
    echo $comma_sep_services; 
?>
```

My question is: What do I need to do so that they are listed in the same order that they appear on the edit page ( R,Mi,Ma,P,RMV)? Bearing in mind that they will not always ALL be checked.

I have tried messing around with unserializing but i don't know enough about it.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://www.eliasinteractive.com/blog/sorting-data-from-custom-fields-in-wordpress/) might be of interest. It's one of the few solutions I've seen that doesn't involve editing Wordpress core files.

You could also try [this modified get_post_custom function](http://blog.tinkerworkshop.com/wordpress-get_post_custom-wrong-order/) that orders the key/value pairs by meta id instead of the "date modified" order returned by `get_post_custom`.

A third option would be to sift through [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/how-to-make-multicheck-for-post-page-meta-box).

**Update: Silly Me!** PHP can sort arrays any darn way you want, and it just gets a teeny bit tricky when that's not numerical or alphabetical. If alphabetization works for you, attempt the following:

```
$key="sqr_services";  
get_post_meta($post->ID, $key); 
$sqr_services = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key );
asort($sqr_services);
foreach ($sqr_services as $key => $val) {
    echo "$val\n";
}
```

If you want to learn yourself more complex array sorting, [be my guest](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Me? I'll stick to ABCs.

**Update: Silly You!**
In response to your comment about checking for and displaying individual values in your `$sqr_services` array, alls you needs to do is check [in_array()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp):

```
if (in_array('Recorded', $sqr_services)){echo 'Recorded';}
if (in_array('Mixed',$sqr_services)){echo 'Mixed';}
if (in_array('Mastered',$sqr_services)){echo 'Mastered';}
if (in_array('Produced',$sqr_services)){echo 'Produced';}
if (in_array('Re-mastered for vinyl',$sqr_services)){echo 'Re-mastered for vinyl';}
```

It's less flexible in that if you add a value to the array (add a new tax term), it won't start showing up until you check for it in your loop. I'm guessing that's not gonna be a problem, though, as this seems like a pretty finite set of options.

Comment: that is what I want but: That is used to sort individual custom fields. I am having trouble implementing that to sort seperate elements in One custom field (sqr_services). pointers? I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with what should accomplish what you need!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That works great! however alphabetical won't work as I need the order to be output as it is in the array function above. Like I said, I'm a newbie and I really appreciate your help. I've been told that I need to call each element individually and then rebuild the array. But I'm having trouble getting a single element to display. Do you know how to call, for instance, just  'R' => 'Recorded'  ? - im going to poke around the page you sent the link for as well.

Comment: Awesome! Just had to change 'Recorded' to 'R' etc. THAT IS A HUGE HELP! I am going to try to take it a step further as I've already chalked this whole week up to a "learning experience." I'd like to be able to implode the output. If you have any pointers for that, awesome. If not - you've been a huge help. I'll post whatever I come up with. Thanks again!